# Установить шрифт calibri light

Tags: css, шрифты

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Calibri light;
  font-style: normal;

  src: url(calibri_light.woff);
      }

p {
  font-family: Calibri light;
```

Ну никак вообще, на макете одно на сайте другое. Синтаксисы всякие разные ставил не помогло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прогоните шрифт через  [шрифтобелку](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) или аналогичный генератор (например, http://everythingfonts.com/font-face), получите набор сгенерированных шрифтов и стили вроде таких

```
@font-face { /*HelveticaC Bold*/
font-family: 'HelveticaCBold';
src: url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.svg#HelveticaCBold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что если название шрифта состоит не из одного слова, а из нескольких, то название нужно брать в кавычки.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibri light';
}
```

и при использовании тоже

```
p {  font-family: 'Calibri light'; }
```

Также обратите внимание, что в сгенерированные стили в `src` вам нужно будет добавить путь к папке, в которую вы положите шрифты, например, `../fonts/`
Подключенный таким образом шрифт будет  поддерживаться во всех современных браузерах, и в старых версиях ие, кроме совсем уж древних.

Comment: спасибо! теперь всё понятно)

Answer (score 0):

Тоже, сколько бился — не смог внедрить шрифты стандартным методом. Как альтернатива fontsquirrel — javascript-плагины, примером которых служит [Сufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/). Поддерживается древними и современными браузерами, о достоинствах и недостатках см. [здесь](http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/cufon). От себя добавлю, что даже если [проставить галочки в нужных местах](http://mirwp.ru/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Cufon21.gif), отображаются далеко не все спецсимволы, включая такие распространённые, как «кавычки-ёлочки»; также не меняются цвета у [посещённых и активных ссылок](http://htmlbook.ru/content/tsvet-ssylok). Спасибо.